# how do i add a row in a google fusion table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have tried looking this up and saw this help
You can add rows to an existing table in two ways:
Use Edit > Add Row to enter a new row one-at-a-time
Use File > Import more rows to bring in rows from a file

But the Edit add row and File import are greyed out when I go into my table.

How else can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check on qouta : search for : 400,000 cell as well as 100MB. May be your table exceeded the quota. Hope this help.